# pd.ExcelFile: file contains lists of floats, but the lists are imported as a string

Tags: python, excel, string, list, pandas

I exported lists of floats to an excel file which i now want to import again as a dataframe. I get a 10x7 dataframe, which looks all good, except that all my lists are stored as one string each (which makes sense I guess, as excel doesn't know what lists are, right?). I'm using this code to import the file:

```
pd.ExcelFile('fitness.xlsx')
```

Using the converter parameter doesn't help. Do you know whether there is an easy way to import my lists as lists containing floats directly? Should I maybe export to a different format in the first place? If so, which one could handle my dataformat? At the moment my entries look like this:

```
In:
xl_var.loc[xl_var['stimulus'] == -2, 'first spike'].values
Out:
array(['[14.25, 11.649999999999864]'], dtype=object)
```

This is how my imported dataframe looks like. You see that my last column even contains 2D lists, which makes converting afterwards a bit messy.

[image: my dataframe]

And this is how my excel file that I want to import looks like.

[image]

Comment: I don't think its a 2D list, just a long list that Pandas is not able to display, try  pd.set_option('max_colwidth',50) and see

Comment: I don't know how to prove it to you, but I know that "average spike shape", the last column, contains several lists that are stored in one list (that is 2D right?). I'm afraid you  just have to trust me for now :p

Comment: No trust issues here, I just thought of one possibility and asked you to try:)

Answer (score 0):

String representations of lists can be converted to lists by using [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval). For a single column, use `.apply()` as in:

```
xl_var['first spike'].apply(eval)
```

If you want to convert all of the columns you can use `.applymap()` with a list of the columns to convert:

```
cols = ['first spike', 'number spikes', 'peak', 'undershoot']
xl_var[cols] = xl_var[cols].applymap(eval)
```

In the case of your last column, you will either need to use string functions to remove the 'array' so that `eval` can process them like python lists, or you can import `array` from `numpy` to allow `eval` to convert them to `numpy` arrays.

```
from numpy import array
xl_var['average spike shape'].apply(lambda x:eval(x, globals()))
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import array

xl_var = pd.DataFrame.from_items((('stimulus',[-2, -1.75]), 
                                  ('first spike',['[14.25, 11.65]', '[14.15, 13.27]']), 
                                   ('arrays', ['[array([1,2]),array([3,4])]','[array([5,6]),array([7,8])]']) ))

In :
xl_var['first spike'].values
Out:
array(['[14.25, 11.65]', '[14.15, 13.27]'], dtype=object)

In :
xl_var['first spike'].apply(eval)
Out:
0    [14.25, 11.65]
1    [14.15, 13.27]
Name: first spike, dtype: object

In :
xl_var['arrays'].values
Out:
array(['[array([1,2]),array([3,4])]', '[array([5,6]),array([7,8])]'], dtype=object)

In :
xl_var['arrays'].apply(lambda x:eval(x,globals())).values
Out:
array([list([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]),
       list([array([5, 6]), array([7, 8])])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was looking for! I will try it later and come back to you.